# How to display List<T> in List Box?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to display the List I create on List Box and i don't know how

I have a class in which I add a new book to List 
C# code

```
public class Manager
{
    static List<Book> lstBook = new List<Book>();
    public void AddBookM(int isbn, string author, string des, string name, float price, ushort quantity, DateTime dateTime, string edition)
    {
        Book book = new Book(isbn, author, des, name, price, quantity,dateTime, edition, new List<string> { "" });
        lstBook.Add(book);
    }
}
```

now in XAML i want to see the books in the List in the ListBox and in the AutoSuggestBox i want to search for books in the list and that this will open up possibilities for completion
XAML code

```
        <AutoSuggestBox Name="SBSearchBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="500" FontSize="20" BorderBrush="Black" Header="Search" PlaceholderText="Write here!" Margin="0,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="SBSearchBtn_TextChanged" QuerySubmitted="SBSearchBtn_QuerySubmitted" SuggestionChosen="SBSearchBtn_SuggestionChosen"/>
    <ListBox Name="SearchList" Width="500" Margin="140,194,860,400" Background="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="25"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For displaying the items in the `ListBox` you need to do the following :

Firstly, you need to define a item template for your `ListBox` so that you can specify how your list items will look like. For simplicity I have only bound `name` and `author` properties from `Book` class.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="SearchList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding author}"></TextBlock>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I would recommend using a [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead of just using a `List`, since you want to update the list items based on what user searches.

```
private ObservableCollection<Book> lstBook = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
```

Next, in the Page's `Loaded` event (or any event that you might want based on your requirement) set the `ItemSource` of the `ListBox` to the `ObservableCollection` you created (`listBook`).

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Setting item source of the list box
     SearchList.ItemsSource = lstBook;

     //Adding an entry to lstBook 
     AddBookM(1, "auth", "des", "name", 2.55f, 10, DateTime.Now, "edition");            
}
```

You should now see an entry added to the list view . The advantage of using `ObservableCollection` in this scenario is that whenever you make changes(add/remove) any item in the `ObservableCollection<Book> lstBook` your UI will automatically be updated.

Thus when you call `AddBookM()` again, you will see that the new entry is also added to the `ListBox`.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it manually:

```
lstBook.Items.Add(book); // of course this is working only a ToString command to the Book class
```

You didn't say what ListBox you were talking about so I just assumed you were talking about the ListBox in the Windows Forms library.

Hoped I helped you!